# Modify multiple cells with a formula in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to modify two cells by executing a function in an excel cell, without using an event, but it seems impossible, ideas or alternative solutions that do not require an event or a subroutine ?

Name of function: MyFunction

```
MyFunction = OtherFunction1([string], [double])
    
'    Try One: calling a subroutine
    Evaluate "FireYourMacro(" & Application.Caller.Offset(0, -3).Address(False, False) & ")"

'    Try Two: SENDING A KEYBOARD SIGNAL to let me modify other cells
    Application.SendKeys ("{ESC}")
    
'    Try Three: Trying to slect other row inside the form
    Range("Q" & row).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=OtherFunction2(RC[-14],RC[8],RC[-1],RC[25],1)"

End Function

Private Sub FireYourMacro(ResultCell As Range)
    ResultCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=OtherFunction2([string], [String], [double])"
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel tries very hard to stop you doing this. There is an internal restriction that stops functions that are called from the spreadsheet (not from macros) modifying other cells. And for good reason: to avoid breaking the calculation tree (the dependencies between cells) and avoiding circular references. As you hint, there are ways around this but IMHO you are just storing up trouble, which may manifest in the form of corrupted sheets down the line. Instead create a function which returns a 2-cell array, rather than a single value.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel4-excel12 for information on the difference classes of functions.